# Is it a good practice to add attributes in Interface (OOP)

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

See the objects below:

```
interface IMedia
{
    public function getThemed();
    public function getDownloadLink();
}

class Video implements IMedia
{
    public function getThemed() {}
    public function getDownloadLink() {}
}
```

If there are some common attributes such as:

```
public $size;
public $uploadedDate;
public $hitCounts;
```

Can they be added to IMedia? Or is it recommended to use abstract class in that place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Muneer

First of all it's not possible. Interface doesn't allow this. I'd suggest to do something like this:

```
interface IMedia {

}

abstract class AbstractMedia implements IMedia {
  public $property = "value";
}
```

Comment: so you mean, only abstract class allows of implementing attributes, and should avoid it from interface?

Comment: @Muneer: Yes interfaces only allow constants and method stubs. You will need to use abstract class like he suggested.

Comment: abstract class or regular class both are good candidates. in interfaces it's not possible, PHP won't allow you to do this it's a syntax error. only methods and constants are allowed in interface.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in general you'd like to be as abstract as possible of course. So accessors/mutators totally make sense in order to avoid type casts just for the accessors/mutators. There would be now win introducing an abstract class just for property implementation.

Comment: what if I converted the IMedia interface into abstract class and add both attributes and methods in it?

Comment: I'd ask, what would be the win? You lose abstraction and gain an implementation of trivial code. Btw: you need to implement getter and setters to do that, just as in Java. What is the exact plan?